# unable to browse to codeigniter custom controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, netbeans, wamp

I am having problems with codeigniter 3, I am using netbeans as my IDE and wampserver.
I was able to browser successfully to 'localhost/ci_test/' (ci_test is the name of the project/website') and it served me the default welcome.php controller,
however I tried a 2nd controller inside the CI controller folder called 'Test.php', with the following content:

```
<?php 
   class Test extends CI_Controller {  

      public function index() { 
         echo "This is default function."; 
      } 

      public function hello() { 
         echo "This is hello function."; 
      } 
   } 
?>
```

then when i tried to browse to that controller: with the following url:
http://localhost/ci_test/index.php/test
it served me my welcome.php (which is not what I wanted),

then I tried this url:
http://localhost/ci_test/test.php

and I got a response:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /ci_test/test.php was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 Server at localhost Port 80
```

I don't understand what am I missing here...

Note: I did not change the .htacess files that were provided by codeigniter, and left them as is(maybe the problem there).

I only changed the following things in CI:

application/config/config.php:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/ci_test/';
$config['index_page'] = ''
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'PATH_INFO';
```

I hope someone can help here :)

EDIT:
I have read the first 4 answer's and it still doesn't work

EDIT2:
so after I decided to give up, I noticed that my apache server did not have ' mod_rewrite' ON, so i turned it on
tried again the same project and it still did not work, Then I decided to create a new project from scratch and with CI, I added new controller and everything works well now. this is lol...
Thank you very much for all those who tried to help me :)

Comment: Think about it. Your system always starts from 'localhost/ci_test/' If that does not run, all sorts of things dont get setup. So when debugging you always run from the start page to where you want to debug. If you set a breakpoint on the script you are interested in, when you get there via the normal flow of the site, the breakpoint will fire.

Answer (score 1):

You need to access that Test Controller directly then you need to add .htaccess file in the project root..
here is the .htaccess file for avoiding index.php in codeigniter

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

if you add this .htaccess file in the root your problem will resolved..

also don't need to add extention in your url (http://localhost/ci_test/test.php) , this is wrong

```
http://localhost/ci_test/test
```

this is enough to load your controller

Answer (score 1):

welcome controller

```
<?php
class Welcome extends MY_Controller 
{
    public function index()
    {
       $this->load->view('welcome');
    }
}
```

welcome view

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url('test'); ?>">Test Page</a>
```

test controller

```
<?php
class Test extends MY_Controller 
{
    public function index()
    {
       $this->load->view('test');
    }
}
```

test view

```
<h1>Test Page</h1>
```

The views must be named test.php and welcome.php and placed into the views folder.

Let us know how you get on.

---

Have a look at the routes.php file in the config folder

Change `$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';`

to

`$route['default_controller'] = 'test';`

See if that works

If you get an error saying it can't find the page look at the address bar if it is like this

`http://localhost/ci_test/test`

try changing it to this

`http://localhost/index.php/ci_test/test`

Comment: that works, but then I wouldn't be able to access 'welcome.php'
I want to be able to access all of my controllers directly :)

Comment: You need to use hyperlinks to change page.  The default controller is just where you start.  `<a href="<?php echo base_url('welcome')">Welcome Page</a>` should get you back to the welcome page.

Comment: Have you tried using a link to change page? If so what error did you get?

Comment: yes i just tried it from 'test' controller (after i changed $route['default_controller'] = 'test';) to go back to my 'welcome' controller, but that did not work:
Not Found

The requested URL /ci_test/welcome was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 Server at localhost Port 80

Comment: You can't place the hyperlink into the test controller, it has to go into the view.

Comment: why not? it did show the hyper link correctly in the page(which still didn't help) I know that's not a good practice but this was merely for testing.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, codeigniter uses the url . com/controller/method.

You have created a Test controller called Test.php.
To access it you would use...

```
http://localhost/ci_test/test
```

You Do Not put a .php on the end.

Comment: Whoops @anuraj, you had already answered it, and you did a better job!

Answer (score 0):

This is a rushed quick answer... If you are using WAMPServer, check that it hasn't set MultiViews in either your httpd file or the vhosts file if you are using that.